# Selenium Webdriver interpret local file with non html ending as html

Tags: python, selenium

I have downloaded bunch of sites, that has a fileending called snapshot, when I open it

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get("file:///Users/test/website.snapshot");
```

When I open the driver as this, I receive the website as html text (not parsed/interpreted). However, when I rename that file to `website.html` it loads the site correctly. Rather than having to rename those files, I was wondering if there is a way to tell the driver to interpret the path as an html file?

Answer (score 0):

From [SeleniumHQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py) (line 326-330):

```
def get(self, url):
        """
        Loads a web page in the current browser session.
        """
        self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
```

I don't find any additional options to pass to the function `driver.get()`.

Unfortunately, I think you cannot avoid renaming. I suggest this work-around: perform regex matching to rename, then call `eval()`, as follows,

```
txt = 'driver.get("file:///Users/test/website.snapshot")'
to_eval = re.sub(r'\.[a-z]+(?=")', '.html', txt)
#'driver.get("file:///Users/test/website.html")'
eval(to_eval)
```